# Inserting into a table using the result of a MINUS subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, insert, subquery

I'm trying to insert the MINUS values from two tables (sample data) on ORACLE. I can insert all rows but I can't get it to work with the rows that are missing in the other table:

Sample Data:

```
SALES TABLE           SALES2 TABLE           S_DETAILS TABLE               
===================   ===================    ==================
ID_SALE|DATE_SALE     ID_SALE|DATE_SALE      ID_SALE|SALE_DETAILS
100    |12/12/2010    100    |12/12/2010     100    |SHIPPED
101    |5/10/2011     101    |5/10/2011      101    |WAITING
102    |10/9/2012                            102    |SHIPPED
103    |5/10/2011                            103    |PROCESSING
```

My Code:

```
INSERT INTO SALES_RESUME(ID_SALE,DATE_SALE,TOTAL_SALE,SALE_DETAILS)
SELECT A.ID_SALE,A.DATE_SALE,B.TOTAL_SALE,B.SALE_DETAILS
FROM SALES A
     JOIN S_DETAILS B ON A.ID_SALE = B.ID_SALE
WHERE A.ID_SALE IN (SELECT ID_SALE FROM SALES
                    MINUS
                    SELECT ID_SALE FROM SALES2);
```

I want to insert rows into SALES_RESUME when the ID_SALE is in the resulting MINUS subquery, inserting:

```
SALES_RESUME          
==============================
ID_SALE|DATE_SALE|SALE_DETAILS
102    |10/9/2012|SHIPPED
103    |5/10/2011|PROCESSING
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your query would appear to do what you want.  What is the issue?

Comment: a see a date of sales_resume of `10/9/1012`, is it held mistakenly ?

Comment: Well, either you've turned up a hideous-but-very-obvious bug in Oracle (possible, but rather unlikely) or there's something here that's not as you expect it to be. Let's take it one step at a time. First, how many rows are returned if you execute `SELECT ID_SALE FROM SALES MINUS SELECT ID_SALE FROM SALES2`? Second how many rows are returned if you execute `SELECT A.ID_SALE, A.DATE_SALE, B.TOTAL_SALE, B.SALE_DETAILS FROM SALES A JOIN S_DETAILS B ON A.ID_SALE = B.ID_SALE`?

Answer (score 0):

Your query would appear to do what you want.  But why not just write this?

```
WHERE A.ID_SALE NOT IN (SELECT ID_SALE FROM SALES2 WHERE ID_SALE IS NOT NULL);  -- assuming SALES2.ID_SALE is never NULL
```

You already know that `ID_SALE` is in the first table.

Comment: I've tried that way before and now I retried and keeps inserting 0 rows :(

Comment: @Rycerzfrost . . . Add the `WHERE` clause filtering out `NULL` values.

Comment: Still did not work, I'm starting to think that maybe cardinality of tables and referencing are messing something up

Comment: @Rycerzfrost i think S_DETAILS is a look-up table holding code and sales_name. i.e. irrelevant to hold `total_sale`, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

If I got it, I think this query will work

```
SELECT A.ID_SALE,A.DATE_SALE,B.TOTAL_SALE,B.SALE_DETAILS
  FROM ((select id_sale,DATE_SALE from SALES) minus (select id_sale,DATE_SALE from SALES2)) A 
       JOIN S_DETAILS B on A.id = B.id
```